# Getting hash in passing trimmed PHP $_GET in landing URL

Tags: php

Running PHP on WAMP localhost I am trying to pass a `$_GET['sku']` from a page to another page trough URL like

```
<a href="selection.php?sku='<?PHP echo trim($_GET['sku']);?>'" role="button" class="btn to-selection">Add to Selection</a>
```

This passing data to next page but I am getting

> http://localhost:/map/bc/selection.ph?sku=%27MO-1103%27

while the `$_GET['sku']` is `MO-1103`. Why I am getting these hashes before and after the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `'` around the sku `%27` == `'`

```
<a href="selection.php?sku='<?PHP echo trim($_GET['sku']);?>'" role="button" class="btn to-selection">Add to Selection</a>
//       here>>>>>>>>>>>>> ^   and here                >>>> ^
```

So change that line to

```
<a href="selection.php?sku=<?PHP echo trim($_GET['sku']);?>" role="button" class="btn to-selection">Add to Selection</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the HTML itself. They are codes that represent entities that cannot be sent at a URL. %27 represents a single quote.

[Check this out.](http://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/)

Comment: [Percent-encoding](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: Yes. The title is wrong. Percent-encoding and HTML entities have nothing to do with one another.